# how to remove files with the same name in clearcase

Tags: windows, clearcase

There are some files which have gotten added to source control accidentally. All these files have the same name but under different path in a VOB.

How can i delete all these file?

I'm trying to use Find and rm together. Seems not to be working.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and combine [`cleartool find`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-1-14) with del in an exec clause:

```
cleartool find . -name "aname" -exec "del \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Note the `\"%CLEARCASE_PN%\"`, which allwos you to work with file having spaces in the path or name.

Now if those same files are actually added to source control, del wouldn't be enough: you need [`cleartool rmname`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpublib.boulder.ibm.com%2Finfocenter%2Fcchelp%2Fv7r1m0%2Ftopic%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc%2Ftopics%2Fct_rmname.htm&ei=XdFyVP-VBIHiOK3LgagK&usg=AFQjCNFMbB73RMj_1VkmAwJLO_J9cdP-og&sig2=dE3XrE5gizFAKgNEzYJGCw&bvm=bv.80185997,d.ZWU&cad=rja) (you can see [one example here](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425#general-examples))

```
cleartool find . -name "aname" -exec "cleartool rmname \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

The issue is that you will have to checkout the parent folder(s) of those file first, before doing the `cleartool find`.